# Real time data filtering in LabWindows?

Tags: c, filter, real-time, signal-processing, labwindows

My gyro is sending data I need to filter real-time. The data are short, 4 element-vectors that are sent 25 times a second. How do I filter this? All the functions I've found in LabWindow's documentation require an entire array of data and then generate a filtered array of the same length (that seems a bit... weird). How can I filter my data using this weird function?

#### For example, I'd like to:

1. filter the first data set
2. shift by 1
3. filter the new data set taking only the last element of the output array

Thats what filtering using a FIR filter looks like if I recall correctly -- convolving signal with filter coefficients, moving by one sample and convolving again.

Benji

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to the LabWindows/CVI real-time module, therefore cannot see the function prototype you are referring to.  If you provide more specific information, you may get more specific ideas on just how to use the call.

Regarding ideas on a C implementation of a FIR filter, look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997850/fir-filter-implementation-in-c-programming)**