# FIR filter implementation in C programming

Tags: c, signal-processing

Can anyone tell me how to implement an FIR filter using c programming language.

Comment: http://sestevenson.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/implementation-of-fir-filtering-in-c-part-3/

Comment: you may want to check out musicdsp.org for filters, like lists of free codes dating back since 2000.

Comment: "fircoef.h" can be a useful google search

Answer (score 14):

Designing an FIR filter is *NOT* a simple topic, but implementing an already-designed filter (assuming you already have the FIR coefficients) isn't too bad. The algorithm is called [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). Here's a naive implementation...

```
void convolve (double *p_coeffs, int p_coeffs_n,
               double *p_in, double *p_out, int n)
{
  int i, j, k;
  double tmp;

  for (k = 0; k < n; k++)  //  position in output
  {
    tmp = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < p_coeffs_n; i++)  //  position in coefficients array
    {
      j = k - i;  //  position in input

      if (j >= 0)  //  bounds check for input buffer
      {
        tmp += p_coeffs [i] * p_in [j];
      }
    }

    p_out [k] = tmp;
  }
}
```

Basically, the convolution does a moving weighted average of the input signal. The weights are the filter coefficients, which are assumed to sum to 1.0. If the weights sum to something other than 1.0, you get some amplification/attenuation as well as filtering.

BTW - it's possible this function has the coefficients array backwards - I haven't double-checked and it's a while since I thought about these things.

For how you calculate the FIR coefficients for a particular filter, there's a fair amount of mathematics behind that - you really need a good book on digital signal processing. [This one](http://www.dspguide.com/) is available free for a PDF, but I'm not sure how good it is. I have [Rorabaugh](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Digital-Filter-Designers-Handbook-Algorithms/dp/0070538069/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1361437667&sr=8-2) and [Orfandis](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Signal-Processing-Prentice-Series/dp/0132091720/ref=sr_1_sc_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1361437726&sr=1-2-spell), both published in the mid nineties but these things don't really get obsolete.

Comment: Yeah, I already have the filter coefficients. Its easy to generate if u have the stop band and pass band specifications with you. One more question do you have any idea how can I implement FIR filters in cascade. Like suppose i have the input x(n) and i want an output y(n) so my overall transfer function would be a block of 3 small FIR filter blocks i.e. (H(z)=Y(z)*X(z)*A(z) ). My real problem would be how to merge all these three filters together in cascade to get the output y(n). Give me just a rough idea or pseudo code or if you have the code kindly paste it.

Comment: Your options are basically (1) design a single filter for the overall transfer function, or (2) call the convolution function repeatedly, once for each filter in the cascade. As far as I can recall, (1) turns out to to be a convolution too (for each pair of filters combined), but I'd have to go back to my textbooks to be sure.

Comment: Can you kindly check it because I have spent a lot of time on thinking this but couldn't come out with the solution. It would be great if you can help me with this :)

Comment: If you think about it, the combined filter must be equivalent to the sequence of filters. The same "*" operator is used for both, so it's really just [associativity of convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Algebraic_properties). Just make sure you allow for the larger numbers of coefficients (sum the input sizes).

Comment: I understand this thing already. I mean its easy to understand it theoretically, but its difficult to program.

Comment: @D X - OK, but I already provided an (admittedly naive) convolution function. All you need to do is allocate and initialize buffers then *call* the thing.

Comment: ok let me try it. But i am also trying to do it with structures so i guess it would make the code more cumbersome.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `p_out [k] = tmp;` ?

Comment: @Shailesh - looks like you're right - also there's a k in one line where there should be an i. Fixing now.

Answer (score 2):

To combine multiple filters:

Start with an unit impulse (a signal with a 1 in the first position and 0 everywhere else). Apply the first filter. Apply the second filter. Continue until all filters are applied. The result shows how the combined filters convolve the unit impulse (provided the array is long enough that no data was lost), so the values in it are the coefficients for one filter that is the composition of the other filters.

Here is sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define NumberOf(a) (sizeof (a) / sizeof *(a))


/*  Convolve Signal with Filter.

    Signal must contain OutputLength + FilterLength - 1 elements.  Conversely,
    if there are N elements in Signal, OutputLength may be at most
    N+1-FilterLength.
*/
static void convolve(
    float *Signal,
    float *Filter, size_t FilterLength,
    float *Output, size_t OutputLength)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < OutputLength; ++i)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < FilterLength; ++j)
            sum += Signal[i+j] * Filter[FilterLength - 1 - j];
        Output[i] = sum;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    //  Define a length for buffers that is long enough for this demonstration.
    #define LongEnough  128


    //  Define some sample filters.
    float Filter0[] = { 1, 2, -1 };
    float Filter1[] = { 1, 5, 7, 5, 1 };

    size_t Filter0Length = NumberOf(Filter0);
    size_t Filter1Length = NumberOf(Filter1);


    //  Define a unit impulse positioned so it captures all of the filters.
    size_t UnitImpulsePosition = Filter0Length - 1 + Filter1Length - 1;
    float UnitImpulse[LongEnough];
    memset(UnitImpulse, 0, sizeof UnitImpulse);
    UnitImpulse[UnitImpulsePosition] = 1;


    //  Calculate a filter that is Filter0 and Filter1 combined.
    float CombinedFilter[LongEnough];

    //  Set N to number of inputs that must be used.
    size_t N = UnitImpulsePosition + 1 + Filter0Length - 1 + Filter1Length - 1;

    //  Subtract to find number of outputs of first convolution, then convolve.
    N -= Filter0Length - 1;
    convolve(UnitImpulse,    Filter0, Filter0Length, CombinedFilter, N);

    //  Subtract to find number of outputs of second convolution, then convolve.
    N -= Filter1Length - 1;
    convolve(CombinedFilter, Filter1, Filter1Length, CombinedFilter, N);

    //  Remember size of resulting filter.
    size_t CombinedFilterLength = N;

    //  Display filter.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < CombinedFilterLength; ++i)
        printf("CombinedFilter[%zu] = %g.\n", i, CombinedFilter[i]);


    //  Define two identical signals.
    float Buffer0[LongEnough];
    float Buffer1[LongEnough];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < LongEnough; ++i)
    {
        Buffer0[i] = i;
        Buffer1[i] = i;
    }


    //  Convolve Buffer0 by using the two filters separately.

    //  Start with buffer length.
    N = LongEnough;

    //  Subtract to find number of outputs of first convolution, then convolve.
    N -= Filter0Length - 1;
    convolve(Buffer0, Filter0, Filter0Length, Buffer0, N);

    //  Subtract to find number of outputs of second convolution, then convolve.
    N -= Filter1Length - 1;
    convolve(Buffer0, Filter1, Filter1Length, Buffer0, N);

    //  Remember the length of the result.
    size_t ResultLength = N;


    //  Convolve Buffer1 with the combined filter.
    convolve(Buffer1, CombinedFilter, CombinedFilterLength, Buffer1, ResultLength);


    //  Show the contents of Buffer0 and Buffer1, and their differences.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ResultLength; ++i)
    {
        printf("Buffer0[%zu] = %g.  Buffer1[%zu] = %g.  Difference = %g.\n",
            i, Buffer0[i], i, Buffer1[i], Buffer0[i] - Buffer1[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this code snippet did not work for me (Visual Studio 2005).

I did eventually find convolution questions having a great answer:

[1d linear convolution in ANSI C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424170/1d-linear-convolution-in-ansi-c-code/8425094#8425094?newreg=8b535b1f80ed4f71962cddd2376073a8)

For those who don't know - the convolution is exactly the same operation as FIR filtering - the "kernel" is the FIR Filter impulse response and the signal is the input signal.

I hope this helps some poor sap who was looking for FIR code :-)

Comment: You might want to pull out the relevant parts of that other question here (in case that other question ever gets deleted). It also gives you a chance to point out the bits you found useful :)