# converting fixed point number stored as unsigned long to float

Tags: c, fixed, long-integer

I read signed fractional value from sensor in q16.4 format and receive this value through i2c bus as unsigned long. I want to convert this value to float to perform algorithm. I was trying to convert it to float like this:

```
float vOut = (float)read_data * 65536;
```

with no result. Data look like is still `unsigned long` with point. Can you give my advice what will be the best way to convert it correctly?

Comment: Please give an example all the intermediate outputs, as well as the bits if you think that would be helpful.

Comment: All data i read i keep in tab. So after sensor is read tab looks like that tab3={1,45,192};  value is 20 bit// tab[0] contain value of 1st register which contain 12-19 bits of 20 value, tab[1] contain 4-11 bits of 20 value, tab[2] is 3rd register which contain 0-3 of 20 bit (lsb)

Comment: Can you give a description of "q16.4" and an example? My searching indicates that different vendors use different formats; e.g. it's not clear whether it's left-justified within the `unsigned long`.

Comment: See [Is this filter implementation making correct output?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19217464) for a previous question about Q-format numbers, and
[Q (Number Format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28number_format%29) at Wikipedia for information about Q format numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
float vOut = read_data;
vOut /= 16.0f;
```

Dividing by 16 pushes the four fractional bits of the fixed point number into the fractional bits of the float.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not more detail GTG.

```
uint8_t tab[3];
Read_sensor(tab);
unsigned long ul = tab[0];
ul <<= 8; 
ul |= tab[1];
ul <<= 4; 
ul |= tab[2] & 0xF;

// I am fuzzy on q16.4  format, so some assumptions.
// Assuming Bit 19 is the sign bit and data is sign-magnitude
float x = ul & 0x7FFFFL;
x /= 16.0f;
if (ul & 0x80000L) {
  x = -x;
}
```